# Is the "key" prop unnecessary when you are using React to generate static markup?

Tags: reactjs

If I am only using React to generate an HTML string in Node (and I am **not** hydrating the HTML on the client), is setting the `key` prop 100% pointless?

Comment: Yes  I think, since you are not hydrating then no need of key to optimize rendering.

Comment: If you're not rendering the generated html there is no point in using a `key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Since your use-case doesn't deal with any of it, I would say yes it is not required.